# Data Model changes don't get saved and don't take effect (Xcode 8)

Tags: xcode, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I'm trying to make my data model in Xcode 8, and when ever I add entities or attributes and close Xcode it never gets saved! Even when I change the setting in the inspectors view, everything resets to empty. How can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try force quitting ```Xcode``` or restarting your system. Let me know.

Comment: Are you calling save on your `NSManagedObjectContext`? If not, the changes are only made in memory and are not persisted.

Comment: @AlvinVarghese: no luck.

Comment: @MatthewSeaman I'm modeling the data graphically through .xcdatamodeld file.

Comment: Oh I see. Sounds like you may need to file a bug report. I have not tried Core Data in Xcode 8 yet.

Comment: I've been able to add attributes but not entities, which just disappear when you save and reopen the project.  Also, it's consistently resetting to ObjC for code generation in the data model so you need to check / reset that before auto building the subclasses.  On the other hand, it's otherwise generally working for a 25 entity database, except for some flakiness around caches for FetchedResultsControllers, which I've just disabled for now.

Comment: @DanClark exactly! So no fix for now?

Comment: Not that I've found.  So far I've kept my old manual setup of the CoreData stack; perhaps using the new container process adds / changes something that would help but I'm working on other things and waiting on the next drop of Xcode for now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug, I filed it. Thanks any way.